# How I can exclude path in gulp src?

Tags: javascript, gulp

How I can exclude part of gulp src path?
There are many paths:

folder/
folder.ru/
folder.com/

And I need to exclude only folders with .ru & .com at end

in my gulpfile

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify');

gulp.task('run', function () {
        return gulp.src([
            '!landing/*.ru/',
            '!landing/*.com/',

            '!folder/*.ru',
            '!folder/*.com',

            '!folder/*[^ru]',
            '!folder/*[^com]',

            '!folder/*[^ru]/',
            '!folder/*[^com]/',

            'folder/**/js/hello.js',
        ])
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(function (file) {
            return file.base;
        }))
```

and it does't work at all, minify all hello.js in all folders

Comment: just an idea... did you try to change the order and place `folder/**/js/hello.js` frist?

Comment: Yes @Sergeon, i tried. It doesnt work too.

Comment: How about trying to declare a non-negate source first, like this => `gulp.src(['landing/', '!landing/*.ru'])`

Comment: This works for your examples:   return gulp.src('./+(folder|landing)/!(*.com|*.ru)/**/*.js')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this:

```
'!**/*.ru/**/*',
'!**/*.com/**/*',
```